# Javascript function to return page id's

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm lookingfor a javascript function which returns the next value from an array on every function call.. I have created a script but i'm a little stuck now.. is there someone to help me?

My location:

```
resultLocation= "beugen";
```

This should be the identifier to get the correct array of id's. There will be more arrays with id''s for example resultLocation = "mill";

My array of Id's

```
var beugen = [];
beugen[0] = "140";
beugen[1] = "33";
beugen[2] = "121";
beugen[3] = "150";
beugen[4] = "52";
beugen[5] = "68";       
beugen[6] = "70";
beugen[7] = "82";
beugen[8] = "15";
```

My function to return a value. (the next value should be shown on each call of getId (resultLoction)

```
getId = function(resultLocation) {
    var arrayLength = beugen.length;
    page = beugen;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        init_table(page[i]);
    }
}
getId(resultLocation);
```

Now my function keeps on looping and calls the init_table(page[i]) as many times as there are id's in my array. It should get the first (140) on the first call of getId and the 2nd (33) on the next call, and if it reaches the end, it should start over again at the the top.

Maybe an array is not the best solution? I don't really know. Since there are multiple locations?

Comment: what about `Array.prototype.forEach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = -1;
function getId(){
    i++;
    if(i>beugen.length-1){
        i=0;
    }
    init_table(beugen[i]);
    return beugen[i];
}
```

or something like that might work if i understand the problem.

Comment: Excellent. Be careful of scope with the "i" iterator outside the function if you have other iterators using "i"